How to back up and restore Keys Cafe and My Stickers?
I am using a Samsung Galaxy Z Flip5 and migrating to a new Z Flip5.
I spent a week setting up the Keys Cafe with specific tags on 100s of images that enable me to see pop-up suggestions of memes in my text messages and insert them easily. Now that I am switching to a new phone, I need to know how to migrate those tags (app data) to a new phone.  There does not seem to be any backup option.
How to back up Keys Cafe (My Stickers) tags so that I can transfer them to a new phone? I need to know how to back up the settings of the Good Lock / Keys Cafe app.

Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I removed the secondary question regarding app recommendation because it is off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions for apps-only. You might be interested in our sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange instead.

You should try to post in the Samsung Members forum (via app or site)
